# Python eel, picture from path

Tags: python, image, display, eel

When I press a button I need to display a picture. The path to this picture is stored in variable.

This is the main.py:

```
import eel

eel.init('web')

@eel.expose
def set_image_src(image_path):
    eel.updateImage(image_path)

eel.start('index.html', size=(600, 400))

image_path = #path to image

set_image_src(image_path)
```

This is the html file (I am lazy to put here the JS file so I put it into a html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Eel App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Image Display</h1>
    
    <!-- Image tag with id "image-display" -->
    <img id="image-display" src="" alt="Image">

    <script>
        function updateImage(image_path) {
            document.getElementById('image-display').src = image_path;
        }
        eel.expose(updateImage);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: By default, `eel.start` never returns.  And remember that the browser (meaning the Javascript) cannot access paths on your disk.  If you want the browser to fetch an image, it has to have a URLs.